# Multiple string replacements on a 100mb file in python 2.6

Tags: python, windows, string, file, replace

I have a large 100mb file which I would like to perform about 5000 string replacements on it, what is the most efficient way of achieving this?

Is there no better way then reading the file line by line and performing the 5000 replacements on each line?

I also tried reading the file as a string using the .read method when opening the file and performing the 5000 replacements on the string, but this is even slower since it makes 5000 copies of the whole file.

This script has to run on windows using python 2.6

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it possible for the strings you're replacing to appear across multiple lines? ie, multiple words with spaces, etc.

Comment: describe the replacements you're making

Comment: The string to be replaced are ids e.g. Abc-2454 to be replaced with Gb-43. The strings are never split over multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, in this order, until you get one that is fast enough.

1. Read the file into a large string and do each replacement in turn, overwriting the same variable.

   ```
   with open(..., 'w') as f:
       s = f.read()
       for src, dest in replacements:
           s = s.replace(src, dest)
       f.seek(0)
       f.write(s)
   ```
2. [Memory map](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) the file, and write a custom replacement function that does the replacements.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, instead of doing 5000 searches, do one search for 5000 items:

```
import re

replacements = {
    "Abc-2454": "Gb-43",
    "This": "that",
    "you": "me"
}

pat = re.compile('(' + '|'.join(re.escape(key) for key in replacements.iterkeys()) + ')')
repl = lambda match: replacements[match.group(0)]
```

You can now apply re.sub either to the entire file,

```
with open("input.txt") as inf:
    s = inf.read()

s = pat.sub(repl, s)

with open("result.txt") as outf:
    outf.write(s)
```

or line-by-line,

```
with open("input.txt") as inf, open("result.txt") as outf:
    outf.writelines(pat.sub(repl, line) for line in inf)
```

Comment: Works well for a small number of replacements but when do with the 5000 replacements I get a overflow error regular expression code size limit exceeded

Comment: @katrielalex: what a boring world it would be if we only ever used things "as intended"...

Answer (score 0):

You should read in the text using open() and read(), and then use (compiled) regular expressions to do the string replacement. A short example:

```
import re

# read data
f = open("file.txt", "r")
txt = f.read()
f.close()

# list of patterns and what to replace them with
xs = [("foo","bar"), ("baz","foo")]

# do replacements
for (x,y) in xs:
    regexp = re.compile(x)
    txt = regexp.sub(y, txt)

# write back data
f = open("file.txt", "w")
f.write(txt)
f.close()
```